# Simple Python program won't return error message

Tags: python

I created a program that applies discounts and shipping rates based on the number of books purchased. It runs fine except that when I input "0" or less for the retail price, I am not returned the error message "invalid entry".  However the error message for inputting zero or less seems to function properly.

```
discountRate = .4
first_BookShipping = 3
additional_Books= .75

costOfBook = input("Enter book retail price:" )

floatCostOfBook=float(costOfBook)

numberOfBooks = input("Enter number of books purchased from wholesaler: ")

intNumOfBooks=int(numberOfBooks)

bookDisc1 = floatCostOfBook*discountRate
bookDisc2 = floatCostOfBook*(intNumOfBooks-1)*discountRate

CostofFirstBook = floatCostOfBook-bookDisc1+first_BookShipping
CostofAddBooks =  floatCostOfBook*(intNumOfBooks-1)-bookDisc2+additional_Books

def bookcost():
    if intNumOfBooks == 1:
        totalcost = CostofFirstBook
        return round(totalcost, 2)
    elif intNumOfBooks > 1:
        totalcost = CostofFirstBook+CostofAddBooks
        return round(totalcost, 2)
    elif floatCostOfBook <= 0:
        print("Invalid Entry")
    elif intNumOfBooks < 1:
        print("Invalid entry")
    else:
        print("Internal Error")


print("The total wholesale price of books purchased is {}: ".format(bookcost()))
```

Code context (adapted from a Chapter 2 exercise of "Think Python"):

- To apply a 40% discount to all books purchased form a wholesaler
- To charge a 3-dollar shipping cost for the first book
- To charge 75 cents shipping for each additional book

Thoughts? Also, if anybody has any tips on how to make my code cleaner or a more efficient way of writing this, I'm not sensitive to criticism.  Just take into account that I'm a beginner coder so I haven't internalized some methods yet.

Comment: What are you inputting for `numberOfBooks`?

Comment: Think about the execution order here: if you enter in only one book, the first if statement will run and the program with print and exit. If you enter more than one, it will print again and exit. The only way invalid entry will be printed is if you enter less than 1 book with a negative or 0 cost, is that what you want?. Try thinking about the order of your if statements, or think about nesting them. For example, if you move the invalid entry check to the top of the if elif statement, what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would suggest using all_lower_case_with_underscore variable names.

Then, since python is dynamically typed, I would just convert your cost_of_book to a float instead of creating another variable.

Then, space pad your operators.

Then of you want an actual exception to be thrown you'll want to wrap a try block around your input value. It's best to handle that when you get the input.

```
discount_rate = .4
first_book_shipping = 3
additional_books= .75

try:
    cost_of_book = float(input("Enter book retail price:" ))
except(ValueError):
    print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")
else:
    if cost_of_book <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Please enter a cost greater than 0")

try:
    number_of_books = int(input("Enter number of books purchased from 
                                 wholesaler: "))
except(ValueError):
    print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")
else:
    if number_of_books <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Please enter a number of books greater than 0")

#commutative property of multiplication saves some computing
book_disc_1 = cost_of_book * discount_rate
book_disc_2 = book_disc_1 * (num_of_books-1)

first_book_cost = cost_of_book - book_disc_1 + first_book_shipping

#try to keep lines at 79 char limit, using continuation with'\'
add_books_cost =  cost_of_book * (num_of_books-1) - book_disc_2 \
                  + additional_books

def bookcost():
    if num_of_books == 1:
        total_cost = cost_of_first_book
        return round(total_cost, 2)
    elif num_of_books > 1:
        total_cost = cost_of_first_book + add_books_cost 
        return round(total_cost, 2)

total = bookcost()
print("The total wholesale price of books purchased is " + str(total))
```

Comment: Very detailed, helpful response! I haven't learned about "try" and "except" yet, but I will review this code when they are introduced in my studies. @Matt_G

Comment: The *try except raise* syntax is analogous of other languages' *try catch throw* blocks. It tells the interpreter to perform an action and defer to what follows for handling if it encounters a problem. Best to learn this early on, it will save you and your team from headaches in the future. Also, don't forget to choose a best answer, even if it's not mine, as it's a reputation bonus for the person that best answered your question and is a huge motivation for people answering here on StackOverflow. Cheers.

Comment: I don't know if I have enough reputation points to choose a best answer. I don't see an option for it.  @Matt_G

Comment: You should have [that ability](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Do you see grey checkmarks next to people's answers? If not, you may have a waiting period.

Comment: The variable name convention you recommend is often called snake case.

Comment: @Matt_G  is "Input Error" a defined type in Python? I'm getting an error when using it.  Tried to pm you but I don't see an option.

Comment: @MountainScott - Apologies, you can use ValueError for both possibilities. You could create an InputError by inheriting from Exception, but [here's what's in the box](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html), depending on what version of python you're running.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your logic to

```
def bookcost():
    ### here ###
    if floatCostOfBook <= 0:
        print("Invalid Entry")
    ### end
    elif intNumOfBooks == 1:
        totalcost = CostofFirstBook
        return round(totalcost, 2)
    elif intNumOfBooks > 1:
        totalcost = CostofFirstBook+CostofAddBooks
        return round(totalcost, 2)
    elif intNumOfBooks < 1:
        print("Invalid entry")
    else:
        print("Internal Error")
```

Meaning check `floatCostOfBook` first.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I still don't understand why it didn't reach the error message anyway.  I don't see how it had any other option. @Jan

Answer (score 1):

Check for valid input should be done before calculations or any other actions you perform in your code. 
In this case it would be ideal to check after each input.
That will both solve bug in your code and make your code cleaner.

So you would go with something like:

```
while True:
  costOfBook = input("Enter book retail price:" )
  floatCostOfBook = float(costOfBook)
  if floatConstOfBook <= 0:
     print("It should be greater than zero")
  else:
     break
```

Answer (score 0):

Trace through your bookcost() function.  (Hint: Are you sure it's even getting to the "Invalid entry" part?)